# Is there a way to filter a dataframe according to a variably-long list?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to filter a column of a df according to multiple patterns contained within a list. My general goal is to apply this to a checkboxGroupInput command of a shiny application.

I need to filter column, say column "bank" within my dataframe, say "df". Criteria (eg. "bankA" | "bankC" | "bankE") are contained within a list (say selectedbanks<-list("bankA","bankC","bankE")). I want to select any line in column df$bank that meets any of the conditions in selectedbanks.

```r
df<-data.frame(a=1:5,bank=c("bankA","bankB","bankC","bankD","bankE"))
selectedbanks<-list("bankA","bankC","bankE")
```

I have tried with

```r
df %>% filter(bank==selectedbanks)
```

, which neither does always the job, nor is this quite right, as in facts R displays an error concerning different lengths of the objects involved in the filter criteria.

I know the right base method would be to use

```r
df %>% filter(bank==selectedbanks[1] | bank==selectedbanks[2] | bank==selectedbanks[3])
```

, but this doesn't come handy with the fact that I am obtaining the list selectedbanks as input$selectedbanks all at once and with variable length from a shiny application of the type checkboxGroupInput

What I wanted

a  bank
1 1 bankA
2 3 bankC
3 5 bankE

What I get
  a  bank
1 1 bankA

Comment: You can use `filter(bank %in% selectedbanks)`.

Comment: Hmmm.... that is exactly what my answer says ;)

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt - right, and was posted 10 minutes before your answer.

Comment: that's right, I have to credit @H1 for her/his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use %in%:

```
# Library
library(dplyr)

# Your data
df<-data.frame(a=1:5,bank=c("bankA","bankB","bankC","bankD","bankE"))

# Your banks
selectedbanks<-c("bankA","bankC","bankE")

# Filtering
df %>% filter(bank %in% selectedbanks)
```

Comment: simple and effective, great